# Video showing up as white space

Tags: bug, android-app, youtube

On [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/76524/movie-identification-people-in-a-white-room-in-space-shrinking) question, there is a YouTube video in [the answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/76526/5645), on the Android app the video shows up as a white space. There is no indication that it is a video.

Would it be possible to show the video in the app or link to the video on YouTube instead?

> [image: blank space instead of YouTube video]

Comment: They should probably just link to it in some way on YouTube, maybe get the screenshot of the video to display it nicely. Android no longer offers Adobe Flash Player in Google Play and it doesn't come pre-installed on new phones, so there's no way for you to play the video there without requiring a resource that many people won't have.